# details from listview jquery sql

Tags: jquery, sql, html

I have searched and so far what I have found does not apply to my needs. I have a HTML5/JQuery App that loads data into a DB. Then you either enter the employee id, name or lastname (full or partial) and it shows a listview of the search items.
I'm looking into a way of, upon tapping on one item, it requeries the DB and returns the details of that item.

This is my code so far. Any help is appreciated:

```
<div data-role=page id=home>
  <div data-role=header>
<h1>Home</h1>
 </div>

 <div data-role=content>
 <span> Employee Id </span>
 <input type=number pattern=[0-9]* id=empId>    
<span> Last name </span>
<input type=text id=lName>
<span> First name </span>
<input type=text id=fName>
<a href=# data-role=button id=search> Search Employee </a>
<input type="reset" value="Clear Values" data-theme="e" data-icon="delete"/>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role=page id=win2 data-add-back-btn=true>
  <div data-role=header>
  <h1>Results</h1>
  </div>

<div data-role=content>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role=page id=details data-add-back-btn=true>
 <div data-role=header>
 <h1>Details</h1>
 </div>
<div align="center"><img src="img/user.png"></div>
   <div data-role=content>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

var db = openDatabase ("Employees", "1.0", "MIT Employee DB", 65535);

 db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
    console.log("calling populateDB");
    populateDB(transaction);
 });

$("#search").bind ("click", function (event)
 {
var empid = $("#empId").val ();
db.transaction (function (transaction) 
 {
var sql = "select id, empid, fname, lname from Employees" + " where empid like '" + $("#empId").val() + "%' and fname like '" + $("#fName").val() + "%' and lname like '" + $("#lName").val() + "%' order by lname, fname";
transaction.executeSql (sql, undefined,  
function (transaction, result)
{
  var html = "<ul>";
  if (result.rows.length)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
      var row = result.rows.item (i);
      var lname = row.lname;
      var fname = row.fname;
      var empid = row.empid;
      var department = row.department;
      var hired = row.hired;
      var yos = row.yos;
      var mos = row.mos;
      html += "<li data-icon=false " + "id=" + empid + ">";
      html +=   "<a href=#details class=detailslink data-uid=" + empid + ">";
      html += lname + "&nbsp;" + fname;
      html +=   "</a>"; 
      html += "</li>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    html += "<li> Not found </li>";
  }


  html += "</ul>";

   $("#win2").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
  {
    var $content = $("#win2 div:jqmData(role=content)");
    $content.html (html);
    var $ul = $content.find ("ul");
    $ul.listview ();


  });        
  $.mobile.changePage ($("#win2"));
  }, error);
 });

});
// Details***********************************

$("#win2").bind ("tap", function (event)
{
var id = $(this).data('uid');
if (!id) return;

db.transaction (function (transaction) 
{
var sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE empid=?";
transaction.executeSql (sql, [id], 
function (transaction, result)
{ 
 console.log("Tapped");
var html = "<div align='center'>";
if (result.rows.length)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) 
    {
    var row = result.rows.item (i);
    var lname = row.lname;
    var fname = row.fname;
    var empid = row.empid;
    var department = row.department;
    var hired = row.hired;
    var yos = row.yos;
    var mos = row.mos
    html += "<b>Employee Id:</b> " + empid + "</p>";
    html += "<b>Name:</b> " + lname + "&nbsp;" + fname + "</p>";
    html += "<b>Department:</b> " + department + "</p>";
    html += "<b>Hire Date:</b> " + hired + "</p>";
    html += "<b>Service:</b> " + yos + "y / " + mos + "m</p>";
}
}
else
{
html += "No employee";
}
html += "</div>";

       $("#details").unbind ().bind ("pagebeforeshow", function ()
  {
    var $content = $("#details div:jqmData(role=content)");
    $content.html (html);
     $('#details').html(html)


  });        
  $.mobile.changePage ($("#details"));


}, error);
  });
}); 

// End Details************************************************************      

function ok ()
{
}

function error (transaction, err) 
{
 alert ("DB error : " + err.message);
 return false;
}

</script>
<script src=js/employ.js></script>
```

Comment: A fiddle might be handy here.  Also don't we need to know what's in employ.js?

Comment: employ.js is just the raw data, here are the first few lines:

Comment: function populateDB(transaction) { $('#busy').show(); transaction.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Employees');
var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employees (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, empid VARCHAR(6), fname VARCHAR(50), " +
" lname VARCHAR(50), status VARCHAR(1), department VARCHAR(50), hired VARCHAR(20), yos INTEGER, mos INTEGER)";
transaction.executeSql(sql); transaction.executeSql("CREATE INDEX id on Employees(id)");

Comment: transaction.executeSql("CREATE INDEX fname on Employees(fname)");
transaction.executeSql("CREATE INDEX lname on Employees(lname)");
transaction.executeSql("CREATE INDEX empid on Employees(empid)"); console.log("starting db load");
transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO Employees(id, empid, fname, lname, department, hired, yos, mos) VALUES(null,'1001','JOHN','DOE','Accounting','16-FEB-95',18,5)");

Comment: I create this file automatically with a Pentaho ETL script that builds the js directly from an Oracle SQL.

Comment: Where is #win2? Cleaned up a few missing semicolons etc in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3d2tU/6/

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is set the id of the item you want to tap to its associated id in the database, or some other unique value from the database. That way you can throw that unique value back to the database just by the id of the component you tapped (it doesn't even need to be an a, you can do it with a p).  You can also have the event.preventDefault(); so the a doesn't do what it was planning.

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
   console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Instead of doing a console.log you could just perform an ajax call to some php code which will fetch details for that item from the database.

In the success parameter of that ajax query you can call another method which displays the appropriate details right after the id (of the thing you "tapped").

Give it a little tappy.  Tap tap taparoo.

Comment: I'm a newbie on all that, could you elaborate a bit with examples? Even if simple ones, it helps. Thanks.